# The convergence of random variables to standard normal distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, normalization, convergence, chi-squared-distribution, eigenvalues

Let $V_s$ be $n\times s$ real matrix and consisting i.i.d $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ random variables [*]. Suppose that $O_s^1$ is the orthogonal matrix, its first column being the normalization of the first row $V_s$. Hence, we have $V_s^1=V_sO_s^1$ is such that its first row is $[X_s,0,0,\ldots,0]$ where $X_s^2$ is $\chi^2(s)$, $X_s\ge 0$, and the remaining rows are again made up of i.i.d. $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ random entries.

How to show "the remaining rows are again made up of i.i.d. $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ random variables"?

[*]
The Smallest Eigenvalue of a Large Dimensional Wishart Matrix
Jack W. Silverstein
Ann. Probab. 13(4): 1364-1368 (November, 1985). [DOI](http://doi.org/10.1214/aop/1176992819)

Comment: I cannot tell what level of rigor you're looking for, but here's a sketch of the underlying idea to help you get started. The rows are Normal $s$-vectors. You describe an orthogonal transformation that maps the first vector into the first coordinate direction.  Although that transformation depends on $V_s,$ the fact that *any* orthogonal transformation will preserve the distribution implies the dependency doesn't matter, and you're done.